# Countdown embed in simple html

Tags: javascript, html, counter

I try to embedd the following into a html website:
https://www.tickcounter.com/clone/countdown/915856

the problem is when i run it i don't get the timer. But when i run it in fsFiddle i get the countdowntimer.

what am i doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-type="countdown" data-id="915856" class="tickcounter" style="width: 100%; position: relative; padding-bottom: 25%"><a href="//www.tickcounter.com/countdown/915856/my-countdown" title="My countdown">My countdown</a><a href="//www.tickcounter.com/" title="Countdown">Countdown</a></div><script>(function(d, s, id) { var js, pjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//www.tickcounter.com/static/js/loader.js"; pjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, pjs); }(document, "script", "tickcounter-sdk"));</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expect the countdown is showing up but it is only showing the  refs

Comment: What environment are you using (code editor, browser, etc)?

Comment: I am just open the html file with Chrome

Comment: And editor is notepad++

Comment: Someone who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

TickCounter widget won't load when you open your HTML page locally, because its loading script relies on a website protocol. You have to put your code on a real server, so your website address starts with either `http://` or `https://`. That's why your JSFiddle works and your local copy doesn't.